# Android displays black rectangles instead of drawable images after opening openGL context

Tags: android, opengl-es, drawable

I am developing a simple Android app that has a few **Activities**, say: **A**, **B**, **C**, and **D.**
**Activity A** is a splash screen. Calls finish() when same data finishes loading.
**Activity B** displays some information and a few buttons
**Activity C** starts a webview with the content accordingly to the button pressed in B
**Activity D** opens an openGL context.

From Activity A I go to Activity B., from B to C and from C to D.

**Problem I face:** some drawables and a progressBar **display black rectangles** after pressing the **back button** coming back from Activity D (activity that starts an openGL context).
Any ideas where I should look into?

Comment: into your code? ... and we should look into a magic orb to be able to answer this question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` to the `<application>` manifest is a workaround, however does not solve the problem. OpenGL state and context preservation as mentioned by Phil might play a role here.

Comment: Solved the problem!Thanks!

Comment: Solved the Issue it was being caused on the specific Activity and i have added android:hardwareAccelerated="false" to activity tag in Manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Black boxes generally occur when the bitmap resource for an Image is no longer available (such as set to `null` or recycled).

In an openGL view, this can occur when an activity goes to the background, often because of lost context. A good place to start would be looking at the GLSurfaceView documentation, in particular the method [setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setPreserveEGLContextOnPause%28boolean%29).